# Reversing Executable Package

Tags: executable, patch-reversing

I have an `.exe` file that loads some other files when executed, I need to redirect these files and export them. When debugging I know that there is a subfolder `/images/%s.png` where the files in question are referenced.

Is there any way to export these files?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using app.any.run since it logs **all** the files the app created